# How to make Coworkers/Employees feel their work is important

Tags: work-environment, team, motivation

Every year we have a survey at our company where employees get to rate several different aspects of their employment. The results are important to us and we review them and try to improve things where we can.

My team has been split into groups to discuss ways to increase positive answers on this survey and respond to any areas we feel need improvement.

The group that I'm leading right now is looking for ways to improve responses to the question:

*The mission or purpose of my company makes me feel my job is important.*

The company that we work for is a global measurement and data analytics company that provides data on consumers and markets to other companies.

We aren't finding a cure for cancer or anything, but I work with a great bunch of people who all do great work. How do I help make my coworkers feel their work is important?

Comment: Well, we don't have access to the feedback you got from your surveys... what do your surveys suggest? What where the key aspects repeated among employees? What suggestions did they provide, if any? You way you want to improve responses on that question. Why is so? Did that question receive negative feedback? What sort of feedback? ... (in a way I feel that to effectively answer this we would have to work on your company, and know how your culture and current status is).

Comment: Also, what current ways do you have in place to make your coworkers feel their work is important?

Comment: I take it more money is immediately off the table then?

Comment: Couple of answers: I am not a senior or even mid-level staffer. I don't have the authority to give raises. Would if I could, though. The survey was composed of many questions asking employees to rank things on a 1-5 scale. This question averaged out around 3.5. I didn't create the survey and I'm not sure that there are written-in answers that give more closure. Honestly, I feel about the same way: we don't do life changing stuff, but the work/coworkers are nice enough. I was volunteered for this task and to come up with a small action plan. I appreciate everyone's curiosity and advice.

Comment: I might feel that my work was important, without feeling that "the mission or purpose of my company makes me feel my job is important". If I were filling in that survey, I would ask myself how well the company's "mission or purpose" related to my actual job. Maybe others would do the same?

Comment: Say "thanks" to your employees and coworkers often. "Thanks for doing *task*. You helped *customer* achieve their *goal*. Say this at least twice a week to each person.

Comment: You're a data company. Don't you know the hazards of manipulating survey responses? Gather the individual responses, then work together to solve any problems that surface.

Comment: No one is discussing manipulating results. We're looking for ways to improve morale and help employees see that their work is important. The survey exists so that we can get an idea of how employees feel and fix any problems.

Answer (score 2):

> My team has been split into groups to discuss ways to increase
>   positive answers on this survey.

This seems to me to be the wrong objective.  Why are you focusing on "increasing positive answers" rather than on "improving whatever it is the employees are unhappy with".

You might think the two are equivalent. I'd guess the employees do not; I guess they'd think the satisfaction survey was HR nonsense.

Comment: I appreciate the input. When I said "increasing positive answers" I meant to fix or remedy whatever issue at hand might be the cause of the negative responses. It's particularly difficult for me to communicate clearly about all of this because this is not normally my area, or a survey of my design. But I appreciate your input and welcome any further advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> The group that I'm leading right now is looking for ways to improve responses to the question

Just fill out the survey yourself if you want better answers, lol. Your group is going to come up with some absurd motivational poster campaign that will not be worth the paper it is printed on.

You are a data analytics company which exists to sell people stuff. Unless the person is motivated by a desire to make life easy for marketers, they are not going to answer yes on that question. Very few people would work there if they were not being paid.

I suspect whether a person thinks their job is important is more heavily dependent on their project or manager than what the company as a whole is like.

Start with sorting out employee engagement and this number will rise.

Answer (score 0):

Bonuses and a pep talk is the tried and tested method. The talk on it's own is just air, but a little spending money is always well received and remembered. Even a lunch shout would go down well with a few pats on the back.

Comment: I think you might be right. Unfortunately, I don't have the capacity to issue raises. And our company is global, and I think that the survey was too, so a pep talk would be hard to organize. But I do think that the answer lies somewhere in reassuring employees that we respect them and are grateful for their contributions. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Both bonuses and pep talks are effective ways of improving short-term performance and morale, but their effect is negligible in the long term. A high degree of personal involvement in defining the vision and goals of the team/company and regularly providing concrete feedback on the progress and contribution to these goals is quite effective, but that is a much broader strategy than just a peptalk. And it doesn't fit every organization.

Comment: @TvZ na... you just periodically do the rewards.... people don't make careers in a single company anyway. You're just giving business information to people who will leave eventually. Short term is all that is needed. Then when it wanes, do it again. It's worked well for millenia.